# is there a flash/JavaScript library that I can use for video trimming/cutting in my website?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, flash, mediaelement.js, video.js

I want to provide functionality to the user so that they can cut video  from particular start time to end time. The most challenging part is I want this functionality ion client side so that user don't have to upload video to cut it. Is there a javaScript or flash library which I can use for this usecase?

Comment: it is exists a video editors for this

Comment: I need it online. not standalone application nor server side. I want to do it in client side in web app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this. The only library that supports video cutting I've found so far is http://mbatle.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/illusions-in-the-web-a-real-time-video-editor-built-in-html5/, but I haven't tested it. I'm not sure if it can be used "out of the box". I would also prefer something more lightweight myself, but this might provide some useful insights. GIT repo: http://cgit.collabora.com/git/user/mbatle/webvideoeditor.git/.